# How to combine data points in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merging-data

The data frame x has a column in which the values are periodic. For each unique value in that column, I want to calculate summation of the second column. If x is something like this:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1:2,1:2,1:2),b=c(1,4,5,2,3,4))
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 4
3 1 5
4 2 2
5 1 3
6 2 4
```

The output I want is the following data frame:

```
a b
1 9 
2 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate` as follows will get you your desired result

```
aggregate(b ~ a, x, sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   group_by(a) %>% 
   summarise(b = sum(b))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      a     b
#   <int> <dbl>
#1     1  9.00
#2     2 10.0
```